# Round shape Layout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy, I worked on. Layouts, I am thinking of getting a layout in Round shape, is it possible to get a layout in round shape in kivy.

If so, how to get the round shape layout.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet possible to have a **RoundLayout** from **kivy** itself, here are all possible layouts [`here`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#module-kivy.uix.layout). You can still round the **buttons and corners and other stuffs**.